# ASP.NET button changes page - Ends up out of div

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, twitter-bootstrap

The problem happens on [this](http://tauimporter.azurewebsites.net/Test.aspx) page. When you press Button 1 a table is displayed on the page. Pressing Button 2 does nothing at all (empty function), but for some reason the button ends up out of the div it is in.

I use twitter bootstrap CSSs (latest version - 2.2.1)

Here's the markup:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="CalendarImporterWeb.WebForm1" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="Timetable" Src="~/TimetableControl.ascx" %>


<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManagerMain" runat="server" />

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    <!--
        function popupWindow(url) {
            newwindow = window.open(url, 'name', 'height=520,width=500');
            if (window.focus) { newwindow.focus() }
            return false;
        }

        function showControl(controlID) {
            var control = document.getElementById(controlID);
            control.style.display = "block";
            control.style.visibility = "visible";
        }

        function hideControl(controlID) {
            var control = document.getElementById(controlID);
            control.style.display = "none";
        }
    // -->
    </script>

    <table border="0" width=500>

    <tr height="50">
        <td colspan="2" align="left">
            <asp:Button runat="server" id="btnGetCourses" text="Button 1" CssClass="btn btn-info"
            OnClientClick="showControl('ImageSpinner');" onclick="btnGetCourses_Click" />
        </td></tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" updatemode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnGetCourses" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <uc:Timetable id="Timetable1" runat="Server" Visible="false"></uc:Timetable>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <asp:button id="btnStart" class="btn btn-primary" runat="Server" 
            Text="Button 2" onclick="btnStart_Click" />
        <br /><br />
    </div>

    </form>
</asp:Content>
```

And the cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace CalendarImporterWeb
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnGetCourses_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Timetable1.LoadCourses("","","");
        }

        protected void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem:
The TimetableControl had a spare /div in its code. Since it was not visible (ASP.NET Visible property, not HTML visible property) it didn't matter until it was made visible

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have an extraneous "-->" in your markup somewhere - I see it on the rendered page at the top right.